# Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?) during gdb android c project

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, gdb, gdbserver

I built a project via ndk,but unfortunately when it runs in the android emulator,it crashes with the following prompt:

```
[1] + Stopped (signal)        ./secfs secfs-client /data/fuse_dir /data/pwrite/test_11
```

And, then I followed the [tutorial](http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/index.html) to debug my project, but it came to the Assembly files. And it is not easy for me to understand the Assembly files. So, I came to use the core dump.
But, when the system products the core file and I am trying to read the core file with gdb, it prompts the following and gdb doesn't seem to work with it:

```
 Core was generated by `./secfs secfs-client /data/fuse_dir /data/pwrite/test_11'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x4001e7f0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x4001e7f0 in ?? ()
#1  0x4001fdfa in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

In the end, I have no idea what to do next, any idea for it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the (brute) force. Place log statements all over your code and see where it stops. In this way you'll have an idea of what is the part of your code that it is causing the SEGFAULT. Run the application several times and see what is the last log statement. Don't assume that the code immediately following the last log statement is the offending code. Sometimes some log statements don't appear in the log. I think this is because of an internal buffering of the text. That is why you should run the code several times.

Comment: I really wish that this wasn't good advice. But debugging native code on Android continues to be a grueling task, even half way into 2013. So having wasted a couple hours (again) trying to get it working, I'll probably resort to log statement spamming.